# How to get suspended users or deleted users difference via TwitterApi?

Tags: python, twitter, twitterapi-python

I want to get the records that which user is suspended and which one is deleted, is there any way to get?

```
from TwitterAPI import TwitterAPI
api = TwitterAPI(consumer_key, consumer_secret, auth_type='oAuth2')
usersfiles=['',''] #LIST of users
for user in usersfiles:
  print(user,type(user)) #api.request('users/show', users/lookup
  r = api.request('users/show', {'screen_name':user})
  print(r.json())
```

while error is

```
{'errors': [{'code': 50, 'message': 'User not found.'}]}
```

but if i use

```
r = api.request('users/lookup', {'screen_name':user})
```

then error is

```
{'errors': [{'code': 17, 'message': 'No user matches for specified terms.'}]}
```

Furthermore is there any efficient way to perform the task as i have around 400K users

for reference: `https://twitter.com/Harrison5l5po` is suspended and
`https://twitter.com/FourthLongRadio` does not exist

Answer (score 1):

Check for suspended response code for suspended user, it goes in the error with code 63.

For a full list of response codes go to

https://developer.twitter.com/ja/docs/basics/response-codes

Edit

If you have large users, go for batch compliance. Quick start guide:

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/compliance/batch-compliance/quick-start

https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/compliance/batch-compliance/api-reference/post-compliance-jobs

Endpoint url for creating the job

`https://api.twitter.com/2/compliance/jobs`

Response from Twitter, each line per id

```
{"id":"1263926741774581761","action":"delete","created_at":"2019-10-29T17:02:47.000Z","redacted_at":"2020-07-29T17:02:47.000Z","reason":"protected"}
{"id":"1265324480517361669","action":"delete","created_at":"2019-10-29T17:02:47.000Z","redacted_at":"2020-07-29T17:02:47.000Z","reason":"suspended"}
```

You can check the reason at the end of each line (deleted, protected, suspended).

And delete the Tweets or users with those ids to stay in compliance.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting *User not found.* because you are passing twitter **url** instead of **username**.

Now, if you only have url than you can use python regex to extract usernames from it.

Try this:

```
for user in usersfiles:
  print(user) #api.request('users/show', users/lookup
  username = re.search("\w+$", user).group()
  r = api.request('users/show', {'screen_name':username})
  print(r.json())
```

It should work fine!

Comment: i am passing usernames, its not my question dear. I asked "I want to get the records that which user is suspended and which one is deleted"

Comment: Well, code does give you output in json format where you can get whether user doesn't exist or is suspended under *'message'*.
Here is the output of this code:
`https://twitter.com/Harrison5l5po
{'errors': [{'code': 63, 'message': 'User has been suspended.'}]}
https://twitter.com/FourthLongRadio
{'errors': [{'code': 50, 'message': 'User not found.'}]}`